# How to set up RDS_DB_NAME in Rails 4 Puma app on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am unable to get Puma & Rails working together on Elastic Beanstalk.

The error I am getting is

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `RDS_DB_NAME' for main:Object
```

In my database.yml, I have:

```
staging:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV[‘RDS_DB_NAME’] %>
  username: <%= ENV[‘RDS_USERNAME’] %>
  password: <%= ENV[‘RDS_PASSWORD’] %>
  host: <%= ENV[‘RDS_HOSTNAME’] %>
  port: <%= ENV[‘RDS_PORT’] %>
```

I am unsure if I need to define the RDS_DB_NAME somewhere or if it already stored in eb?  What error could I be making?

Comment: You should make sure those quotes are regular quotes, not some sort of funny curly quotes.

Comment: Can you provide the exact name of the solution stack you are using ... something like "64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.5 running Ruby 2.0 (Puma)" or "64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.0 running Ruby 2.1 (Puma)"?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. Replacing the funky quotes in `<%= ENV[‘RDS_DB_NAME’] %>` with regular single quotes for all the `ENV` variables worked